# Update property of object using linq but the method after updating doesnt compute properly

Tags: c#, linq, oop, properties

the property is updating but when the method of the student is called again it computes but returns 0. though, the student exam totalitem and totalcorrect item is updated and has value.

here is the code for student class

```
public class Student : Person, IStudentGrade, IGrade
{
    public List<Exam> ExamList { get; set; }
    public Recitations Recitations { get; set; }

    public double ComputeMidtermGrade()
    {
        var midterm = ExamList.Where(e => e.Term.Equals(Terms.Midterm)).SingleOrDefault();
        var midtermGrade = ((((midterm.TotalCorrectItem / midterm.TotalItem) * 50) / 50) * 0.25) * 100;
        return midtermGrade;
    }

    public double ComputeFinalsGrade()
    {
        var finalsterm = ExamList.Where(e => e.Term.Equals(Terms.Finals)).SingleOrDefault();
        var finalsGrade = ((((finalsterm.TotalCorrectItem / finalsterm.TotalItem) * 50) / 50) * 0.25) * 100;
        return finalsGrade;
    }

    public double ComputePrelimsGrade()
    {
        var prelims = ExamList.Where(e => e.Term.Equals(Terms.Prelims)).SingleOrDefault();
        var prelimGrade = ((((prelims.TotalCorrectItem / prelims.TotalItem) * 50) / 50) * 0.25) * 100;
        return prelimGrade;
    }

    public double RecitaionGrade()
    {
        var sum = Recitations.RecitationsList.Sum(r => r.Grade);
        var recitationGrade = (sum / Recitations.RecitationsList.Count) * 0.25;
        return recitationGrade;
    }

    public double ComputeTotalGrade()
    {
        var totalgrade = ((ComputePrelimsGrade() + ComputeMidtermGrade() + ComputeFinalsGrade() + RecitaionGrade()));
        return totalgrade;
    }
}
```

this works fine as you can see in the first image
[image]

but after updating the properties the returned value is 0 tho the properties has value.

[image]

100% passed in picture 1 as well as new TOTAL GRADE in picture 2 was calculated using this method in student class.

```
public double ComputeTotalGrade()
{
    var totalgrade = ((ComputePrelimsGrade() + ComputeMidtermGrade() + ComputeFinalsGrade() + RecitaionGrade()));
    return totalgrade;
}
```

so can anyone help me why it returns 0 in ComputeMidtermGrade(), ComputeFinalsGrade(), ComputePrelimsGrade()

[image]

view after updating the student grades as you can see the prelim, midterms and finals score are 0. but the prelim score karl has 5/10 score (the property in exam class)

```
public enum Terms { Prelims, Midterm, Finals };
public class Exam
{
    public Terms Term {get; set;}
    public int TotalItem { get; set; }
    public int TotalCorrectItem { get; set; }
}
```

EDIT: 
1st pic 1st view, 2nd pic edit grade, 3rd pic 2nd view after edit

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Debug your code. Find why `Exam.TotalCorrectItem` is 0 after update. Also `((x) * 50) / 50)` is always `(x)`

Comment: it has value Exam.TotalCorrectItem and Exam.TotalCorrectItem you can see it in the last image prelim score: karl 5/10, 5 is the exam total correct item and 10 is the totelitem. but it returns 0 in prelim. i just called the same method that i used in the first image where it calculates the prelim grade.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in case when TotalCorrectItem less then TotalItem, result of operation  `x.TotalCorrectItem / x.TotalItem` will be always zero, because you use int type. Change to double or decimal.

Comment: or use `(double)x.TotalCorrectItem / (double)x.TotalItem`...and store that in a floating point

Comment: i already have condition for that. its already working as you can see in the first image. but once i updated the student grades. then call the calculation methods it returns 0

Comment: when you get total grade zero , what are the values of midterm.TotalCorrectItem, midterm.TotalItem, finalsterm.TotalCorrectItem , finalsterm.TotalItem,prelims.TotalCorrectItem , prelims.TotalItem  at that moment ? 5 and 10 , as i understand

Comment: @Z.R.T ill edit my post. ill upload  a new image for before and after updating of properties.

Comment: try public double TotalItem { get; set; } and  public double TotalCorrectItem { get; set; }

Comment: @Z.R.T i think its not the problem. because im just inputting a grade that is integer.

Comment: when you work with int type, what do you expect from  : 5/10 ? if you expect 0.5, then you are wrong , because it will be 0

Comment: @Z.R.T ohh yeahh. thankssss!! :)). I'm so dizzy right now I overlooked that basic division. Its working earlier because my test data is just 1/1 and when i edit i turn it to 5/10